# OpenCV solvePnP return camera below floor

Tags: camera-calibration

Recent I use OpenCV solvePnP to calibrate the camera. I get some 3D space points on the floor. After calibration I get the camera below floor (z<0). How can I flip the parameters.

Comment: Your question is too vague. You should post your specific code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set a wrong right-hand coordinate system. The issue is solved when use the right coordinate system